# Confluence (Synchrony) using websockets behind IIS8 can't copy or insert large blocks of text

Tags: reverse-proxy, iis-8.5, websocket, confluence

I've got a Confluence 6.1.0 setup running behind an IIS8 reverse proxy doing SSL.  Everything works except for one small problem.

When I try to copy a three or four paragraphs of text, attempt to copy a table, or attempt to insert a new table larger then about 8x8, the Collaborative Editing fails and the text on the bottom bar goes from "Ready to Go" or "Changes Saved" to "Can't save changes".  It will then sit there until you cancel editing, discard your changes, and reopen the editor.

Copying and Pasting smaller blocks of text or inserting smaller tables works as expected.  There is some kind of threshold around 3,500 characters of text is the difference between working and breaking.

The Environment is Windows 2012 R2 with IIS8.5 with SSL running and Confluence 6.1.0.  This happens in both IE and Chrome, I have not tested Firefox.  There are no errors in any Confluence logs, IIS8 logs, or even in the developer console in Chrome.

If I turn off the proxy and go to Confluence 6.1.0 directly, everything works fine.  I also have another environment with Apache installed instead of IIS8 doing the same thing and it also works fine.  This problem appears limited to IIS8 doing WebSockets.

My best guess is that there is a setting in IIS8 that is limiting the amount of data it will proxy.  I just can't find that setting.

Settings I've looked at include:

- Request Filtering

  - Maximum URL Length in Bytes - currently set to 8192
    which is twice the default
  - Maximum Query String - currently set to
    8192 which is four times the default.
  - Maximum allowed content length - currently set at 30000000 which is the default, equates to 28.6MB and is far larger then what I'm doing.
- ApplicationHost.config and web.config system.webServer/webSocket

  - receiveBufferLimit - currently set to 4194304 which is the default and equates to 4MB, also larger then what I'm doing.

Is there another setting that I've missed that would explain why IIS would be chopping off or rejecting the payload?

Comment: We are having the exact same problem, did you find a solution already by any chance?